# R Shiny horizontal section

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I have the graphic of the evolution of a firm`s Assets and I want to draw a horizontal section hat is parallel with the Ox axis from 300000 to 400000, that should indicate the optimal value of this indicator(what the stakeholders want) and the line(the graphic itself) should be over that section to see immediately if the value at a certain time is good or not.

```
#date_a
An         AI       AC    AT
2011    147198  292282  439480
2012    164660  175440  340100
2013    153755  202013  355768
2014    141857  242317  384174
2015    137748  270366  408114
2016    129087  397289  526376

#in ui.r
fluidRow(
                  width="100%",
                  column(4,plotOutput(outputId = "act", height = 100))
                ),
#in server.r
  output$act<- renderPlot({
    ggplot(date_a, aes(date_a$An, date_a$AT)) + 
      geom_line(aes(group=1), colour="#000000") +
      geom_point(size=3, colour="#FF0000")+
      labs(x = "An", y = "Active(lei)") +
      ggtitle("Evolutia activelor totale")
  })
```

Comment: by "horizontal section", do you mean just a horizontal line at both 300,000 and 400,000? Also, inside your `aes()` call you should not have `data_a$`. Instead it should be `aes(An, AT)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this doesn't seem to have anything to do with `shiny`. Your question has to do with `ggplot2`. Boiling down your question to what the real cause of your issue is will help you get help faster. In addition, like I mentioned in my comment, in your `aes` call inside of `ggplot`, you should not put `data_a$` in front of your column names.

With that being said, if you want to have the entire region filled in from y = 300,000 to y = 400,000 then you can use `geom_ribbon`, like this:

```
ggplot(data_a, aes(An, AT)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=1), colour="#000000") +
  geom_point(size=3, colour="#FF0000")+
  labs(x = "An", y = "Active(lei)") +
  ggtitle("Evolutia activelor totale") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 300000, ymax = 400000), alpha = 0.2, fill = "blue")
```

That will give you this:

[image]

You can change the values of `alpha` and `fill` to get the region to look like you want.

If you wanted just two horizontal lines at both 300,000 and 400,000 then you can do this instead:

```
ggplot(data_a, aes(An, AT)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=1), colour="#000000") +
  geom_point(size=3, colour="#FF0000")+
  labs(x = "An", y = "Active(lei)") +
  ggtitle("Evolutia activelor totale") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 300000)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 400000))
```

That will give you this:

[image]